# Are external USB drives on separate USB buses faster?

Tags: usb, external-hdd, lsusb

Is there a speed difference between when `lsusb` shows that two external USB HDDs are on the same bus versus when they are on different buses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each USB bus has a certain transport bandwidth, and if you max out that bandwidth, two devices on the same bus will have to share it, slowing down each of them, while two devices on different busses with separate root controllers won't have to share it.

So the answer is: it depends.

Do you ever use both HDDs at once? What's the maximum I/O speed of the HDDs? What kind of USB bus is it?

Comment: "_two devices on different busses with separate root controllers_" How do I determine if the root controllers are different? "_Do you ever use both HDDs at once?_" Yes.

Comment: Look at `lsusb -t`.

Comment: It appears they're all part of "Class=root_hub".